# How to change read only file to writeable

Tags: spss

Running SPSS 23,
When trying to save a file I get the following error message:

> The specified file or directory is read-only and cannot be written to.
>   The file will not be saved.  Save the file with another name or to a
>   different  location or change the access permissions first

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are trying to write to a directory you have permission to write on - if you gave no path, by default SPSS will write to the SPSS install directory which might require administrator rights.
You can change the default directory for this session by running:

```
cd "c:\users\santosh\somedirectory"
```

If this is not enough and you are sure that the file you are trying to write to is not open, try the following syntax:

```
PERMISSIONS FILE='yourpath\yourfile.sav' /PERMISSIONS WRITEABLE.
```

And try again.
Please make sure, before you overwrite the existing file, that important information is backed up and safe - if a file was locked for editing, there might be a good reason.